# Disable mouse.hide()/cursor.hide()

Tags: windows, mouse, flash, cursor

I dislike when websites and programs use mouse.hide() or cursor.hide(). Is there any way to disable any program from ever using them?

Comment: Block javascript, flash, css, everything but HTML.  Although in that case you lose a lot of content also.

Comment: You didn't mention whether or not this occurs while you are typing, so I'll throw this out there: have you checked the Mouse control panel setting **Hide pointer while typing**?

Answer (score 0):

Have ou tried using Windows accessibility features, like [show lcoation of pointer](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/using/accessibility/locatepointer.mspx) ?